# Match specific pattern with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

I've to make a regex to match exactly this kind of pattern
here an example

**JK+6.00,PP*2,ZZ,GROUPO**

having a match for every group like

**Match 1**

- JK
- +
- 6.00

**Match 2**

- PP
- *
- 2

**Match 3**

- ZZ

**Match 4**

- GROUPO

So comma separated blocks of
(2 to 12 all capitals letters) [optional (+ or *) and a (positive number 0[.0[0]])

This block successfully parse the pattern

```
(?P<block>(?P<subject>[A-Z]{2,12})(?:(?P<operation>\*|\+)(?P<value>\d+(?:.?\d{1,2})?))?)
```

we have the subject group

```
(?P<subject>[A-Z]{2,12})
```

The value

```
(?P<value>\d+(?:.?\d{1,2})?)
```

All the optional operation section (value within)

```
(?:(?P<operation>\*|\+)(?P<value>\d+(?:.?\d{1,2})?))?
```

But the regex must fail if the string doesn't match EXACTLY the pattern
and that's the problem

I tried this but doesn't work

```
^(?P<block>(?P<subject>[A-Z]{2,12})(?:(?P<operation>\*|\+)(?P<value>\d+(?:.?\d{1,2})?))?)(?:,(?P=block))*$
```

Any suggestion?

PS. I use Python re

Comment: what pattern are you looking for? is it `(2 different letter)+(time stamp),(2 of the same letter)*(1 number),(2 of the same letter),(a string)` ?

Comment: are comma separated blocks of (2 to 12 capital letters)[opt. (+ or *) and a number]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally go for a 2 step solution, first check that the whole string fits to your pattern, then extract the groups you want.

For the overall check you might want to use `^(?:[A-Z]{2,12}(?:[*+]\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?(?:,|$))*$` as a pattern, which contains basically your pattern, the `(?:,|$)` to match the delimiters and anchors.

I have also adjusted your pattern a bit, to `(?P<block>(?P<subject>[A-Z]{2,12})(?:(?P<operation>[*+])(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?)`. I have replaced `(?:\*|\+)` with `[+*]` in your operation pattern and `\.` with `.?` in your value pattern.

A (very basic) python implementation could look like

```
import re
str='JK+6.00,PP*2,ZZ,GROUPO'
full_pattern=r'^(?:[A-Z]{2,12}(?:[*+]\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)?(?:,|$))*$'
extract_pattern=r'(?P<block>(?P<subject>[A-Z]{2,12})(?:(?P<operation>[*+])(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?))?)'
if re.fullmatch(full_pattern, str):
    for match in re.finditer(extract_pattern, str):
        print(match.groups())
```

http://ideone.com/kMl9qu

Comment: yes that's definitely a solution, don't know why I didn't think that before! thank you also for the optimizations

Comment: Do you know why the regex I did doesn't work? I defined the 'block' group who works, so why a ^block(, block)*$ doesn't? mmmm

Comment: Because it is a backreference, so it tries to match the literal match again, not the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the pattern you were looking for:

> (2 different letter)+(time stamp),(2 of the same letter)*(1 number),(2 of the same letter),(a string)

If thats the case, this regex would do the trick:

`^(\w{2}\+\d{1,2}\.\d{2}),((\w)\3\*\d),((\w)\5),(\w+)$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8B3C6e/2

Comment: Look at the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tH5j5t/1) I did, it takes the right information but doesn't invalidate the string if the pattern is wrong

Comment: @Misterfrederx what did you test?